# Send pending notification after login

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Push notificaiton from [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/). I am able to run the project succesfully. I have added that in my project. All the things are working perfectly. Now i want to implement that when an user logout from my app he should not receive any message from the server. and after when he logged in again he should see all the pending notifications. I am in a fix , don't know what to do. 
Here is my logout code:

```
public static void logout(Context context){             

//      GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);           

        AppConstant.setBooleanSharedPreference(context, AppConstant.SP_IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to developer docs you shouldn't unregister from GCM in such situation. You can read about it here http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg-why

Instead of unregistering you can check in GCMIntentService in onMessage() method if user is logged in and decide what to do with a notification.
So in your case you can save notifications into DB when user is logged out and show them when he logs in.

Comment: what if an user signin in another device? In that case he won't receive the notificaiton. But theoratically he should receive that pending notificaiton.