# How to receive pending gcm notification which were send during logout after login

Tags: php, android, web-services, google-cloud-messaging

I am working with gcm notification.I am able to receive gcm notification successfully during login.But when I logout and login again then I am not able to receive notifications which were send to me during my logout session.

Comment: This is confusing.. The way GCM works, if a message is pushed but the device is offline (or in your case, the user is not logged in), it should stay in the GCM queue. Then upon going online, GCM will then push the messages. Your post is lacking some details. Post your client code for GCM, your server code, and I think your sample payload would also help. Do read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section if you're new here. :)

Comment: Maybe you set your `time_to_live` with a low value?

Comment: hey please explain how to use time_to_live.I have not use this in my code and I think you are near to what I am looking for.

Comment: If that's not familiar to you. You should read more on the GCM official docs.. particularly the [Lifetime of a Message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime).

Comment: I have read that but how to use time_to_live.Do we have use in web service or in android code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you update or login with google your gcm token will refresh. So pending notification will not be deliver to that user who is logout during you send notification.

Comment: You mean to say there is no solution for this?

Comment: Acoording to gcm Docs (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) "The listener service's onTokenRefresh method should be invoked if the GCM registration token has been refreshed:", In short ***NO*** .

Comment: you have to update the token every time when it will refresh.

Comment: acutally I am not at all using this way for gcm notification.I am using public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService way in which protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) method is called to register the device.

Comment: But your GCM token will change every time when you logout from that app

Comment: yes you are right but even then I am looking for some appropriate solution for this something like this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473051/send-pending-notification-after-login

Comment: If you want to send notification to logout user you can use xmpp with gcm. you can save or update token with in your xmpp database and use xmpp server to send notification when user will login again with new GCM token.

Comment: we can't store it in mysql server?Is its mandatory to use xmpp database for this and are you sure this method will work?

Comment: You can use message which will sent from your xmpp server as notification to users may be this will work otherwise I don't know anything else which can help you in this problem.

Comment: One uses XMPP if they need two way communication (server-client, vice-versa) in their application. If what he needs is just receiving the pending message(s) upon logging in again.. How does XMPP help? I don't see the point.

Comment: I only send message to a particular user or group of users using my xmpp server and that message is converted to a notification by my client app. But user's can't send any message to me, even they don't know they are receiving messages. I can send notification with or without Images with this trick. When user login back and connect to my server on any device they are getting old notification too. ;-p